# Junit Testing JAXBContext to throw JAXBException - testing failure scenario using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method to test for jaxbexception,There are initial validations before this method so i cannot send invalid request to occur JAXBException. Only way i see is to use MOCKITO, tried it but didn't work for me.

Method to be tested:

```
 private String methodtoBeTested(Object request, Class clazz)
{
    try
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(request, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    }
    catch(JAXBException e)
    {
        LOG.error("jaxbexception encountered" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So far i tried :

```
JAXBContext jaxbMock = mock(JAXBContext.class);
    Marshaller marshalmock = mock(Marshaller.class);
    when(jaxbMock.createMarshaller()).thenThrow(JAXBException.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);` is calling a static method on `JAXBContext` and you can't use `Mockito` to mock that. You *could* use `PowerMockito` but perhaps that's overkill.

One way you could test this for the negative is to find a `Class` that it cannot be used with - e.g. one which has no JAXB annotations, or is private, or an inner class, or something else it wouldn't naturally like. Calling this method with an input that it genuinely fails with, will be a better test of your error handling than mocking a failure, which may not realistically reflect a real-life one.

Alternatively, put this particular micro-module of code behind an interface, and mock the whole of it to enable you to test how its callers would handle it hitting an error.